# Path traced by the point of closest approach to the origin of a circle with two fixed points

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Consider the following construction:

1. Fix two points, $A$ and $B$, in the plane.
2. Add a free point $C$.
3. Draw a circle through the three points $A$, $B$, and $C$.
4. Define the point $I$ as the point on our circle which is closest to the origin.

Now, I believe, as we move $C$ anywhere on the plane, the point $I$ traces a closed path (somewhat resembling an egg). For your convenience, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR33x.png) is a graphical representation of the construction, as well as the path traced by $I$.

My goal is to find an ergonomic expression for the path traced by $I$, as a function of $C$, which I can use in further calculations.

So far, my approach has brought me to the following construction, in the complex plane:

1. Define $W = \frac{C - A}{B - A}$ as a helper variable.
2. Define $M = (B - A) \cdot \frac{W - |W|^2}{W - \overline{W}} + A$, this is the middlepoint of the circle.
3. Define $I' = M \cdot (1 - \frac{|B - M|}{|M|})$, equivalent to the point we are looking for.

Now, I believe that this works, but the expression for $I'$ is a little unwieldy, and I am looking for help in obtaining a simpler one, if possible. If it is any help (perhaps this is an *xy problem*), my end goal is to solve the inequality $|I| < n$, that is to say I would like to find out which values of $C$ give a circle that approaches the origin within a certain radius.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the "end goal" can be achieved with a simple geometric construction. That's because the points where the locus of $I$ (bue in the figure) intersects the limiting circle (centred at $O$ and of radius $n$, black in the figure) are also the tangency  points of the limiting circle with one of the circles passing through $A$ and $B$.

There are two such tangent circles. To construct them, note that their centres must lie on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and also on the hyperbola with foci $A$ and $O$ whose points $P$ satisfy $|PO-PA|=n$. These are the pink and green circles in figure below.

Point $C$ can then lie in either of the two lunes formed by those circles.

[image]